# jQuery iterating through a html "blob" / document - unable to access properties

Tags: jquery

**Premise:**

I want to take a chunk of html off of a document, and then change the div id's and reprint the same html chunk with some modifications, in the same document, below the original html. I would repeat this 'X' times.

**Problem:**

I can't seem to access the divs in the html chunks when I'm trying to reprint.

**My steps**

- I have some html on a page, enclosed in a div,

  ```
  <div id="a">
     <div id="aaa">...</div>
     <div id="bbb">...</div>
     <div id="ccc">...</div>
  </div>
  ```

I extract this html using jQuery

```
var h = $("#a").html();
```

I convert it to a jQuery object

```
var jqObj = $(h);
```

And then look through the div's in it

```
$("div", jqObj).each(function (idx, elem) {
       //elem is a HTMLDivElement type
        var jq = $(this);
       // I want to access the id, class etc. of the div elements here            
    });
```

The 'each' iterates correctly as many times as there are divs.

But no matter what I do, whether $(this).attr("id") or elem.id or whatever else, it all returns as undefined. I printed the $(this).html() and it seems to have the content, but all the id's from the div seem to be stripped out.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get hold of the id's (I need to change them before printing out the html again) and other properties of this HtmlDivElement?

**Problem solved**

See comment below on using clone(). Here's my function in case someone else needs it.

```
function Inserts() {
    //get the html    
    var h = $("#a").clone();

    //now turn it into a jquery object
    var jqObj = $(h);

    //now parse it, let's make some modifications
    var someID = "0";
    $("div", jqObj).each(function (idx, elem) {

        if ($(this).attr("id") == undefined)
            return;

        $(this).attr("id", someID + "_" + $(this).attr("id"));
    });

    $("#target_div").append(jqObj.html());
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead of getting the html and creating new elements. After cloning, you can change the properties before you reinsert the block where you want.

Note that it's quasi mandatory to change the id of your objects before reinserting. Use `attr("id","anotherId")` to do it.

Comment: that was fast and accurate! Wasn't aware of clone()

Answer (score 1):

`clone()` is the way to go, its simple and built for such tasks.

Btw, the problem with your approach was,

You were doing,

```
var h = $("#a").html();
var jqObj = $(h);
```

i.e. you were trying this,

```
var jqObj = $('<div id="aaa">...</div><div id="bbb">...</div><div id="ccc">...</div>')
```

But, markup string passed to `$` function does not have a root element and `$` function needs a root element to convert a markup string (string with tags) into a jQuery object.

So, if you need a solution in your approach , you can do something like this.

```
$(function(){
    var h = $("#a").wrap('<div />').parent().html();
    var jqObj = $(h);  
    $("div",jqObj).each(function (idx, elem) {
        //elem is a HTMLDivElement type
        var jq = $(this);
        console.log(jq.attr('id')); 
        // I want to access the id, class etc. of the div elements here            
    });
});
```